# AWS Redshift Leader Node-Only Function with table reference

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to pass the server address, server port, and the count from a table in one query in AWS Redshift. i.e.

```
select inet_server_addr(), inet_server_port(), count(*) from my_table;
```

> ERROR: 0A000: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not
>   supported on Redshift tables.

I understand that this query does not work because I am trying to execute a [Leader Node-Only Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html) in conjunction with a query which needs to access the compute nodes.

I am wondering, however, if there is a work around available to get the information that I need in one query execution.

Note: Editing the above query to use common table expressions (cte), sub-queries, views, scalar-functions etc results in the same error message.

Note 2: PostgreSQL System information functions like `inet_server_addr()` are currently [unsupported in AWS Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html), however, they work when called without a table reference.